# Taurus / JMeter stucked on preparing phase

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I'm trying to run a simple Taurus scenario to test the tool.
I'm on windows 10 with Taurus 1.15.1. I have written a simple yaml file, and try to run it.
The result is the following :
[image: Taurus run]

In the taurus logs we can see that the last line is about the plugin manager :

`[2021-01-07 11:46:55,273 DEBUG root] Executing shell: ['C:\\Users\\fabie\\.bzt\\jmeter-taurus\\5.2.1\\bin\\PluginsManagerCMD.bat', 'install-for-jmx', 'C:\\Users\\fabie\\Documents\\taurus\\2021-01-07_11-46-53.562154\\modified_requests.jmx'] at .`

So I tried to execute this command in another window to check the log. Everything looks fine, but it never returns which could explain why taurus is stucked in this preparing phase:
[image]

The bat itself is a single line Java command :

```
java %JVM_ARGS% -jar "%~dp0\..\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar" --tool org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD %*
```

The yaml file is the following :

```
execution:
- concurrency: 2
  hold-for: 1m
  ramp-up: 0m
  scenario: yaml_example
  
scenarios:
  yaml_example:
    retrieve-resources: false
    requests:
      - http://www.redirection-web.net/
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taurus documentation states that

> If there is no JMeter installed at the configured path, Taurus will attempt to install the latest JMeter and associated plugins into this location (by default this is: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/bin/jmeter). You can change this setting to your preferred JMeter location (consider putting it into the ~/.bzt-rc file).

The problem only occurs with the first option, when Taurus is in charge of providing a Jmeter instance. I fixed it by downloading the latest Jmeter version and referencing it in the taurus script. It doesn't explain why the first option doesn't work, but it provides a simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sufficient, I would suggest [increasing JMeter logging level to maximum](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by changing `<Root level="info">` to `<Root level="debug">` in the *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

Or if you prefer [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Taurus-Configuration-Syntax) for some reason:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
        log_level: DEBUG
```

Also run Taurus in more verbose mode by passing [`-v` command-line argument](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Top-Level-Settings) to it like:

```
bzt -v your_test.yaml
```

Most probably `jmeter.log` and `bzt.log` files will contain some clues so you would be able to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the log levels, but nothing useful was logged. I didn't find the reason why the jmeter downloaded by taurus doesn't work, so I downloaded jmeter on my own and referenced the new one, then it worked. It doesn't explain the problem but I can continue my tests.